# What is the best book for learning how to model the CMB Power Spectrum?

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, cosmic-microwave-background

I would like to understand the science behind the CMB Power Spectrum.  How the harmonics are calculated (distance to surface of last scattering, sound horizon), how the amplitudes are predicted (Baryonic loading, mass on a spring, etc.), the science behind the damping, etc.  As these books tend to be very expensive, I want to buy just one.

Answer (score 2):

You can find good reviews online that go into the details you are looking for

- M. Bucher, "Physics of the cosmic microwave background anisotropy", [*Int. J. Mod. Phys. D* **24**:2 (2015) 1530004](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218271815300049), [arXiv:1501.04288](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04288).
- W. Hu, "Lecture Notes on CMB Theory: From Nucleosynthesis to Recombination", [arXiv:0802.3688](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3688).

That being said, understanding how the CMB works is deeply connected with some other fundamentals:

- Cosmology
- Galaxy formation and evolution

So if you really want the science behind the power spectrum I would recommend a book that goes through all those details before. I like [Galaxy Formation and Evolution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521857937), it has a modern view of all these subjects, and it finds a nice balance between details and number of topics to discuss.